# The root cause for Boeing 787 Dreamliner battery problems

Tags: safety, boeing-787

[Wikipedia's B787 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner_battery_problems#Solution) states that:

> The causes of the battery failures are still unknown. There is still concern that because the root cause of the fires were not identified, the solutions put in place by Boeing will not be able to cover the full range of possible failure modes.

But 787 was still cleared for flight after it fixed the "Fire Propagation" problem by correctly packaging its batteries in a fire resistant material.

My question is :

1. What is the actual cause of such Battery problems? (If it's known?)
2. If Boeing is not able to resolve the root cause of the fires (according to Wikipedia), then is it safe for the Dreamliner to be allowed to fly?
   *Because what they have done to resolve the problem does not appear to be a permanent solution, but more of a temporary fix.*

Comment: The cause is not confirmed, but the containment measures taken are satisfactory and ensure safety in case of battery fire.

Comment: I don't see what the question is. We know that the cause is unknown; the regulatory authorities feel that the containment measures make hte plane safe enough. What is left?

Comment: I firmly believe that this is an answerable question, and we do know what caused fires in batteries. See this [question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14871/how-much-is-the-boeing-787-dreamliner-affected-by-teething-troubles-now-one-yea), and then this [link](http://avherald.com/h?article=45c377c5/0023&opt=0)

Comment: This could be part of a more general problem with modern batteries catching fire.

Comment: @anshabi Neither the question or the article you point to states conclusive proof of cause of the battery failures. This **is** an unanswerable question, for now.